# what does the wtpversion mean in the Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2

using maven, what does the wtpversion mean in the Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[wtp](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) adds web application support to eclipse.  If you want to develop Maven based web applications with Eclipse, you should rather use Eclipse [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin.

As for wtpversions, [this link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#What_version_of_Eclipse_does_WTP_work_with.3F) has a mapping of wtpversion and eclipse versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the abbreviation of Eclipse `W`eb `T`ools `P`roject and you can use in maven > pom.xml under the `<build>` tag:

```
<!-- Eclipse project -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
        <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
        <!-- Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

From: [How To Create A Web Application Project With Maven](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/)